# How to fill the radio button with the value I receive from a txt file?

Tags: php

Here is my question:
First, I read a txt file and then successfully parse them into pieces. I fill some of the value in my form, and it works fine. But I encounter troubles when filling the value into radio buttons.

Here is my code:

```
$content = read_txt_file($file_path);
$array = parse_report_txt($content);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
     $$key = $value;
}
```

The above 2 functions: read_txt_file, parse_report_txt works well, but I'm really curious why the radio buttons can't be filled as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What you did for fill radio button ?

Comment: I don't see any radio button code, so at this point you are just making us guess

Comment: use <label> tag with id or class.and then use javascript to fill the radio button value

Comment: The weird part is, when I fill all the other blank without connecting to their id or name and everything works. But radio button doesn't. :(

Comment: There are two ways to do it . One is through JQuery , pass the array to JQuery and split the values and populate the radio button . Other solution is set a session variable and reload the page and in the top first check whether session exists or not . If yes , then get the values and populate the radio buttons .

Comment: Radio buttons are not like text inputs - if you want to specify which button in the group to be active you have to attach `checked` attribute in its HTML tag.